# Angular 8 Filter - Unresolved function or method on string on .toLowerCase()

Tags: angular, typescript

I wrote a filter to  filter from a list when the user is typing. For parameters it takes the original list(items) and the searchtext to look for.

I changed the datasource of the list and it is now coming through in JSON form and the searchtext is throwing an error that toLowerCases() is a unresolved function or method string.

Can someone shed a bit of light, thanks.

```
transform(items: any[], searchText: string): any[] {
    console.log('Items from filter', items);
    console.log('searchText', searchText);

      if(!items) return [];
      if(!searchText) return items;

      searchText = searchText.toLowerCase();

    return items.filter( it => {
      return it.fullDivisionBranchCode.toLowerCase().includes(searchText);
    });
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] reproducing your issue.

Comment: @jpalov What does your call to transform look like? Are you certain you're passing a string into searchText? I know it's typed as a string but there are ways around that.

Comment: @Keeleon, that is a good point, I am going to post the JSON for it, but I think you could be correct that it is not actually a string that is getting passed.

Comment: @jpalov Kindly, try `searchText = searchText.toString().toLowerCase()`.
Doesn't need to change it everywhere to string. If, it's not a string

Comment: @AbhishekChokra that throws a simular error, what is getting passed to the filter maybe a the collection and not a string.

Comment: If that's the case and to avoid in future too one can use strict types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably it's not because of searchText.toLowerCase().

Try check if there is a value before using .toLowerCase() method like that:

```
return items.filter(it => it.fullDivisionBranchCode && it.fullDivisionBranchCode.toLowerCase().includes(searchText));
```

Comment: That worked, it stopped throwing the error. But my list isn't populating but that should be an easy fix. THANKS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

This might be because it not a string in that case use some null check for that like

```
return items.filter( it => {
  return ((it.fullDivisionBranchCode||'').toLowerCase()||'').includes(searchText);
});
```

Hope it helps!